# Skipping input in C from files

Tags: c, file-io, fgets

What I need to do is read several lines of text that are numbers, skip the first portion of the text, and copy values to an array.

**Original text Example:**

```
1/1/11 5 4 23 5

2/2/22 5 23 18 35
```

**Needs to read as:**

```
5 4 23 5

5 23 18 35
```

then store values to an array.

Since `5` occurred `3` times it would print:

```
Number: 5, Occurred: 3
```

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){

FILE *file;
file = fopen("words.txt", "r");

if (file == NULL){
    printf("Problem opening file.");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Opened successfully.\n");
int NumArray[150];


while (!feof(file)){
    fgets(NumArray, sizeof(NumArray), file);
    puts(NumArray);
}
```

This prints my file as a whole but im stuck at this point . Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Even with what you have, I would strongly suggest you use a standard-compliant C compiler (returning `void` from `main` isn't standard compliant), and turn up your warnings as errors to pedantic levels. `fgets` doesn't take an `int[]` as its storage buffer, and `puts` doesn't either.

Comment: Is there always 4 values after the date?

Comment: No there will be 6 numbers on each line